# Where is the MMC CARD that I see in the my computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, disk-management, diskpart

There is no MMC CARD connected to my computer, But when I open MyComputer I see a MMC-Card drive there that has 487 MB of 487 MB free space!

[image]

Disk Management output :

[image]

And Diskpart output :

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: THIS-PC
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online          488 MB      0 B

DISKPART>
```

**Q1: What is this MMC CARD and where is it?!!**

**Q2: Why I see different free space for *DISK 0* in Disk Management window and in DiskPart output? (In diskpart output I see only 1024 KB free space for disk 0!!!)**

Comment: It might not be relevant, but do you see the card if you start Windows in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 1):

Q1:

Many computers (e.g. most modern servers) have some sort of built-in flash memory, that may show up as CF, SD, MMC Harddisk or whatever. Post vendor and model of your computer to confirm

Q2:

Disk 0 has a single megabyte (1024 KB) of space, that is not assigned to a partition - this is different than space, that is assigned to a partition, but not yet used. Small parts of a disk might easily be not assignable to a partition, due to alignment issues.

Comment: This is not a modern server! This is DELL Vostro 1015!

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate questions:

> Q1: What is this MMC CARD and where is it?

Somewhere in your computer you have a 512MB SSD card.

Physically where is not something we can answer, but if it is a laptop then look carefully at its sides.

> Q2: Why I see different free space for DISK 0 in Disk Management window and in DiskPart output? (In diskpart output I see only 1024 KB free space for disk 0!)

Diskpart shows free unallocated disk volumes.
Disk management shows the free space on the volumes.

Compare it to a bookshelf which is 5.1 centimeters wide.
You have two notebooks on it, one 1.5 cm wide, one 3.5 cm wide and you have 1 cm free space on the shelf.

Diskpart shows the free space on the shelf.

Explorer and disk management show how much unused pages (space) you have in the notebooks.

Comment: I am sure that there is no SSD CARD connected to my computer! There is only one socket for memory cards on my computer and it is empty!

Comment: Any attached monitors with an internal USB hub and cardreader? (Inspired by the long forgotten part of the monitor I am sitting behind.)

Comment: This is DELL Vostro 1015, so as far as I know there is no any other socket, neither in the lid and monitor nor in the body.

Answer (score 0):

The DELL Vostro 1015 has an Expresscard/34 slot.  Look there

ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-1015_Service%20Manual_en-us.pdf

Comment: I already checked it! It is empty!